# Post to Microfeed using SPD 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, newsfeed

I tried to create a new post in our Microfeed/newsfeed in Sharepoint 2013 using a Sharepoint Designer workflow. My idea was to create a list item in the list with the "Create item" action.

When executing the workflow the workflow responses with the following error message:

> Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to https://site/teams/teamsite/_api/web/lists(guid'...')/Items Correlation Id: ... Instance Id: ...
>   Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

The message is the same for list and for site workflows.
Using a SP 2010 workflow it is different but not very helpful, too:

> The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information. Access Denied

"Workflow can use app permissions" is activated and for custom lists there are no issues.
Unchecking the "Automatically Update The Workflow Status To The Current Stage Name" box was not successful ([Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131805/unauthorized-access-on-microfeed-workflow-error))

Could anyone provide a more or less simple way to post on the newsfeed with Sharepoint Designer Workflow?